# Replacing Darlington with MOSFET for capacitive discharge circuit into a solenoid?

Tags: mosfet, electrolytic-capacitor, darlington, scr

I have the following circuit and criteria and am wondering if it makes sense to replace the Darlington transistor with a MOSFET, and if so how would that change the circuit? This circuit turns on T1 when powered and there is an inrush of current to charge the capacitors. When they are charged, the LED lights. Several solenoids are connected to the board through the J2/J3 connection and when a switch (actually a relay) is pulsed, T1 shuts off and the capacitors discharge through the solenoid after which T1 conducts again, charging the capacitors.

- Voltage either AC or DC (thinking of replacing D1 with a bridge
  rectifier)
- 12-18 V coil resistance is between 2 and 10 ohm depending
  on the solenoid
- I don't know the solenoid inductance
- Current pulse to throw the solenoid electronically would be 20 ms to 50 ms (but I would want to calculate an upper safe limit for the components. I am assuming relays can switch at these speeds)
- There can be at least 8 solenoids connected if not a lot more, but only 1 or 2 would switch at the same time
- Solenoids would switch randomly and intermittently, but never more than once per second. Usually there would be several seconds between using a solenoid, but often minutes.
- T1 is a BD679, can I replace it with a TIP120 if I stick with a BJT?
- I have 1N4004s for the diodes, is that overkill?

[image: Capacitive Discharge Circuit]

I want to replace the switches/relays with a MOSFET too and also trying to learn about where a MOSFET or an SCR is a better choice. Maybe an SCR in place of the switches/relays? I remember using a "Thyristor" to pulse a flash tube a long time ago.

These are for track switches on a model railroad. Some are single coils that reverse polarity to open and close a directional turn. Other coils are "twin-coil", one coil pulls the track to one side and the other pulls it back to the original position.

Comment: The large L and C values might resonate in that 50 ms period, depending on series resistance.  A better approach might use power FETs with Ron much lower than the coil R with one shot pulses.

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating your explanation, see if right: C1 & C2 are charged, then D2 lit, and people(?) push buttons, one or two of them gets prize. Correct?

My compliment to the designer: Very Good analog engineer! The key is how to charge enough big capacitor safely, hold the caps discharged until loads are removed, and then recycle the sequence.

First, the answer is: Yes you may replace T1/Q1 with a NFET, though not straight replacement. Changing SW1..SW to FET is no issue, I think.

If I explain what the current circuity does, you would understand, can come up with a solution, no need of whole thing designed, I hope.

a) Importance of Q1 being a BJT, in the given circuitry, is the emitter follower configuration. While C1 & C2 starts charging from low voltage, charging current/speed gets limited/regulated by R1..R4 settings, while adding Q1 gain (Ie = Ib + b*Ib).

b) Engaged loads (switches) bring Q1 base low, turns off Q1. D4 makes sure Q1 base is deep low, lower than emitter if possible.

c) Once C1 & C2 have been discharged, and while any of the switches are depressed, Q1 is turned off by the mechanism in b). If any of the solenoids were still active, it is due to the current (holding) through R1..R4.

d) Relays/Solenoids are often slow to fully activated. You need to trust the calculations and measurements from the working unit. That could be different if the solenoids change.

e) Fun of arcade pinball is the touch, very mechanical. You may want to keep the touches when replacing SW1..SW.

-- continue to finish --
f) Base working mechanism of BJT starts with current through base.   SCR is similar (gate current), though latches until current (A-K) is removed, FET (enhance mode / depletion mode) works by the voltage on gate. IGBT, Hybrid of BJT and FET works like BJT driven by FET. etc. etc. All I can say in this space is that those are not mutually "drop in replacements". It requires some consideration. Which is "good or bad", all depends on use.

g) TIP120 seems to be a good replacement for BD679. Capacitor charging time can be shorter, due to the higher hfe, the current gain, though likely insignificant.

h) All 1N4000 series are the same for current handling, 1A forward, 20A surge. 4004 does not hurt anything, if it is replacing 4001. It will work, though I wonder how long it will withstand possible max current 18V/1ohm (2 x 2 ohm solenoid) = 18A peak, not for mil or industrial app. Meantime, I doubt the designer threw that low impedance solenoid in the circuit. It sounds like you had this circuitry working for a while. My advice would be; no broken no fix, ha ha. Estimation sometimes do not replace what it is. Otherwise, if you are worried, you can add any sort of current limit in series.

---

All these involve guessing.

Fly-wheel diode on solenoid: Worst case, without that, you will find strange wear-out and intermittent operation problem after a long run. When current is interrupted on inductor, it can go to any voltage high, and it does in practice, easily exceeds rating of active components, more arching on contacts. If it really bothers, easiest way is, scope the wave form on solenoids. If no sudden interruption of current, you may safely remove those.

Adding resistors in series: That is a good resolution, helps many aspects, use enough wattage, may change the solenoid response significantly.

Speed of relays and solenoid: I have a different opinion. Those easily takes over hundreds of mS. If your eyes can track the mechanism movement, it is not tens of mS. If those mechanical parts move in tens of mS, there are multiple adverse effects.

---

You are going to have some controller/sequencer to run the railroad, and Willing to revise electrical system.(?)

When "first win" is not the system, BJT and surrounding circuitry is to limit charge current (power sharing), protect components from over current, limit the continuous current to the solenoids, and to generate pulse. Since you are going to provide control signal, well formed pulse, all that can be simplified. You would have enough size of dc power (full bridge rectified is ok), likely with much less capacitance, separated from the main power supply, than no worry about current limit, except in case protection (fuse?). No FET, no BJT needed. I still do not believe the solenoids are 2 ohms. If so, it could be for very low voltage. What decides the magnetic field is the current through the coil, not the voltage. You can find the acting point using variable power supply, then approach the power design. Now you can freely drive the solenoids using FET-s (recommended), pulsed.

---

I see you have the control over drive signal -micro-controller-. Then, your simplest approach will work as well, no cap is ok. There are a lot of room you can play, as long as you can characterize the solenoid.

Comment: These are for track switches on a model railroad. Some are single coils that reverse polarity to open and close a directional turn. Other coils are "twin-coil", one coil pulls the track to one side and the other pulls it back to the original position. Going from a current controlled device like the Darlington to a voltage controlled device like an FET requires a change in the circuit. What are the changes?

Comment: Fred, I need to understand the whole system more to suggest how FET can be here and there. But, it will likely be a new design. Instead, from your explanation, I can make another guess, adding in the main text up there, due to the limited space given in the comment box.

Comment: Hi Jay. I am experimenting with 3 different designs. Two are tested and work one is just charging banks of capacitors, one for each solenoid. The other is the circuit above. It will work with at least some solenoids "snaps" them back and forth with gusto ;) I was  trying to learn this circuit and try replacing T1 with an FET. My 3rd circuit is using an H-Bridge and a microcontroller. No capacitors, just a 2A power supply at 12-18V through the half bridge for one direction and the other half for the other direction.

Comment: Hi Fred, I wrote up there. I know it is not giving the circuitry. But, it seems you are on the right track, finding what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have some major problems with your design, it will fail. If your coils are 10 Ohm they will draw 1.2 Amps. If 2 Ohms you will draw 6 amps, in either case the 1N004 will fail. It is not an overkill it is undersized.  You will possibly get some current limit from the transistor section but the bulk capacitance will override some of that at the turn on point. The limit depends on the gain and the available current to the base. Electromechanical relays are relatively slow devices  typical models can switch and settle in 5 to 15 ms. Expect to test a few to get the speed you want. I would suspect they are probably to slow for what you want to do.

Comment: I can add resistance to low resistance coils. Some I have found now are 20 Ohms. Also, don't think I need the flywheel diodes on the coils here since they are never connected to any circuitry by nature of the fact that they are only connected by momentary switches, correct?

Comment: @Fred The energy stored in the relay coil will happily arc across your switch, which will wear it out quickly. Putting diodes across the relay coil is still strongly recommended.